# Problem installing RVM

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I have executed the commands as prescribed in the instructions at the rvm website but things don't seem to work..

Fetching the code from the git repository runs smoothly but when I try to use

```
 rvm notes
```

Error:

```
/usr/local/bin/rvm: line 73: /home/cody/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

flashes in multiple lines and doesn't stop till I hit ctrl+C..
I am running Ubuntu 8.04 and currently I am running ruby 1.9.2..
Sorry, if I am missing out any necessary information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you installed rvm using sudo or as root. If that is the case, remove it and reinstall without sudo. It works perfectly fine installed for the local user.

Comment: According to your snippets, it looks to have installed into /usr/local. Look in there for a directory called "rvm" or ".rvm" and delete it. You also need to delete /usr/local/bin/rvm.

Comment: There are four more files... rvm-auto-ruby, rvm-prompt, rvm-shell and rvmsudo, should I delete them too??

Comment: Yes, anything referencing rvm.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ack, I didn't mean to post this as a comment on the question. Anyway, if I had to guess, I'd say you installed rvm using sudo or as root. If that is the case, [remove it](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/troubleshooting/#bottom) and reinstall without sudo:

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.rvm $HOME/.rvmrc /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh \
  /usr/local/rvm /usr/local/bin/rvm
sudo /usr/sbin/groupdel rvm # this might fail, it's not that important
```

Open new terminal window/tab and make sure rvm is removed:

```
env | grep rvm
```

The output should be empty, sometimes it's needed to relogin, after it's empty you can continue:

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

It works perfectly fine installed for the local user.

Comment: Delete /usr/local/bin/rvm and find where the rvm install directory is and delete it too. It looks like it should also be under /usr/local somewhere. Try "find /usr/local -name rvm".

Comment: Had a similar issue but was due to installing default gem file with sudo. changing the user from root fixed for me.

Answer (score 3):

DId you add this line to your `~/.bashrc`?

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # This loads RVM into a shell session.
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, for anyone who tried to install RVM using sudo and is now pulling
their hair out trying to get it to install in `$HOME/.rvm`, here's what
did it for me:

When you installed RVM using `sudo`, it created a file `/etc/rvmrc`, which contains the following:

```
umask g+w  
export rvm_path="/usr/local/rvm"
```

This makes all future attempts at installation (even when not run as sudo)
install into /usr/local/rvm, which is NOT what you want for a single
user installation. So remove `/etc/rvmrc` and then you can run

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

and it will install properly into `$HOME/.rvm`

Answer (score 2):

> I have executed the commands as prescribed in the instructions at the rvm website.

*WHICH* commands? There are several pages containing instructions to install RVM depending on whether you want a [single-user "sandbox"](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) or are installing [system-wide](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/deployment/system-wide/) for a multi-user system as the administrator.

Because you have RVM in `/usr/local`, I think you tried to do a system-wide install but didn't get it right. For 99% of us, that is the wrong installation method, and instead you should use the single-user installation, which is simple and puts everything in `~/.rvm`.

Either way, be sure to read the entire instructions. And, if doing a single-user install, finish the install with the "Post Install" modifications to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` for a single-user, then start a new terminal session.

When using the single-user install [NEVER use sudo](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rubies/rubygems/) to install gems to a RVM-managed Ruby, even though the instructions for a gem might say to.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the section "Troubleshooting your install" [here](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/).  Since you are on Ubuntu, you probably need to make further mods to you .bashrc

Answer (score 0):

in .bashrc have you changed the

`[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`

to

`if [[ -n "$PS1" ]]; then`

and added this to the end of the file:

fi

`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"`

Answer (score 0):

I just [had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038364/ruby-rvm-install-error-could-not-source).

It turned out that many files in ~/.rvm/scripts/ and ~/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/ which obviously should be executable did not have execute permissions. Running a script on both directories to set all files to executable solved that immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have got same problem after installation. Then I restarted terminal and it started working poperly.