# Ruby: RVM Install Error "Could not source..."

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, file-permissions

A reinstall of RVM produced the following errors when done:

```
WARNING:
          Could not source '/Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/base' as file does not exist.
          RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
          Could not source '/Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/version' as file does not exist.
          RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
          Could not source '/Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/selector' as file does not exist.
          RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
          Could not source '/Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/cd' as file does not exist.
          RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
          Could not source '/Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/cli' as file does not exist.
          RVM will likely not work as expected.
WARNING:
          Could not source '/Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/override_gem' as file does not exist.
          RVM will likely not work as expected.
cat: /Users/developer/.rvm/VERSION: No such file or directory
/Users/developer/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/rvm: line 133: __rvm_conditionally_add_bin_path: command not found
```

I reinstalled after I wrestled with trying to get RVM to work with Textmate and RVM behavior became strange (reporting it didn't have gemsets it would list) so I ran:

```
rvm implode
```

... and then manually removed the executable. Then I ran the install again by scrupulously following the [single user instructions from the home site.](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

After I spotted the errors, I investigated the paths and found that many files in `~/.rvm/scripts/` and `~/.rvm/src/rvm/scripts/` which obviously should be executable did not have execute permissions.

RVM would not run at all so I set the executable bit on all the files in the two directories and that seems to have fixed things. (So far at least.)

Googling, it seems that other people have hit this problem but there seems to be no explanation or resolution. I would like to find out if this is a known issue and whether I should reinstall yet again.

I'm running rvm 1.6.9 on MacOS X 10.6.7

Comment: I had this issue today on a Gentoo box. I think its because RVM is stupid enough to make you install by Git; I bet theres a bad commit in there. Maybe it uses tags; I dunno. The install process is ridiculous.

Comment: I haven't seen this at all, on any of my installations, but I haven't had to do a clean install for a while, only updates, which might be masking the problem. I'd recommend bouncing it off the author. You can find his contact info using `rvm -v`.

Comment: "The install process is ridiculous." How so? I run the bash command and it installs.

Comment: I got the same errors, tried to debug it for a long time, and then discovered that (at least for me) despite the errors rvm ran just fine.

Comment: I got some weeks ago also some install issues and think, there was a corrupt version. You really should reinstall it with a newer version now, and hopefully it will success. RVM is still under hard development and lots of things changed in the last versions, also pathes! Keep that in mind, clean everything before try a new, fresh install.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking that now that I understand the ruby environment a little better that I'll give it another go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

they are **warnings**, not errors. I've got similar ones on my ubuntu linux box (but not on another, with same RVM version). so, it's not strctly related to OSX.

your RVM installation should work anyway.

Comment: In my book, warnings are just errors that haven't happened yet. But then, I learned to program on old school C so I'm paranoid. ;-) I reinstalled rvm and it seems fine now.

Comment: FWIW, I stumbled to this error and the instance wasn’t working. The version file is installed when the stable version is installed, when installing unstable version directly that file is not created.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. If you have installed system-wide it is definitely looking for both the system-wide configuration... and some hard-coded user scripts. Which is weird.

quick fix:
ln -nfs /usr/local/rvm /Users/developer/.rvm

Answer (score 1):

it looks like all you need is to create that missing file.

in your terminal type:

`touch /Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/version`

`touch /Users/developer/.rvm/scripts/base`